# Make a callback to android methods from libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, callbacks

How can I make a callback from libgdx to an Android method? I want to use the method to overwrite a file in the internal memory.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I resolved it as if it was a simple callback in Java or a delegate in C# thanks

Comment: I believe you can click the "tick" over your answer to consider the question answered so it is not listed as unanswered questions any more.

Comment: Your answer is terrible. It gives no solution to the OP. You should at least provide some instructions, or some code or to make it into a real answer. Others like [matjaz](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/23743/matjaz) would like to know the answer.